# Convert string array representation of integers into array of integers in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift

How can I convert this:

```
let numbersStringArray = "[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -8, -9, -10]"
```

into an array of integers:

```
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

I know one way to implement thin swift is to do like this:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
var numbers = numbersStringArray.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]")).componentsSeparatedByString(",").map { formatter.numberFromString($0)?.integerValue
 }
```

But I need more shorter coded solution please.

Comment: Why? If what you have works...

Comment: Is it always going to be JSON formatted?

Comment: Is numbersStringArray an array of Strings or a string formatted to look like an array?

Comment: a string that looks like an array

Comment: and will it always contain correctly formatted integers?

Comment: @Wain I guess yeah, we can say like that .... always JSON formatted

Comment: @Polis yes, always integers. positive, negative or zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like something shorter if possible. Something like Array(numbersStringArray)

You can do this by simply creating a convenience initialiser through an `Array` extension.

For example, decoding the string through JSON, as [@Eric D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37391692/2976878) suggests:

```
extension Array {

    init?(jsonString: String) {
        guard let array = (
            try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(jsonString.utf8))
            ) as? [Element] else { return nil }

        self.init(array)
    }
}
```

```
let numbersStringArray = "[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -8, -9, -10]"

if let numberArray = [Int](jsonString: numbersStringArray) {
    print(numberArray) // prints: [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
}
```

Here we're returning an optional array to reflect the fact that the types could mismatch (the conditional downcasting to `[Element]` could fail), or the JSON deserialisation could fail.

Or spitting the string up manually as [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37391442/2976878) suggests:

```
protocol StringInitialisable {
    init?(string: String)
}

extension Int : StringInitialisable {
    init?(string: String) {
        self.init(string)
    }
}

extension Array where Element : StringInitialisable  {

    init(string: String) {
        self.init(
            string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[]"))
                .components(separatedBy: ", ")
                .flatMap(Element.init)
        )
    }
}
```

```
let numbersStringArray = "[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -8, -9, -10]"

let numberArray = [Int](string: numbersStringArray)
print(numberArray) // prints: [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

We're using a protocol here in order to explicitly specify the types that can be used for this initialiser – namely those that can be initialised with a string. This method won't return an optional if the type casting fails, it will simply exclude any type mismatches from the returned array. You could change it fairly easily to return an optional result if you want though.

Which method you use is completely up to you – if your string is always in a JSON format, then I would recommend going with the first option for increased flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're telling us that your String is always formatted as JSON, you can use `NSJSONSerialization` to decode it to an array:

```
if let data = numbersStringArray.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
        json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []),
        array = json as? [Int] {
    print(array)
}
```

This is not shorter than your example but I think it's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter is

```
let numbers = numbersStringArray.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]"))
                                .componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
                                .flatMap { Int($0) }
```

---

In this case

```
numbersStringArray.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]"))
```

can be also replaced with

```
numbersStringArray.substringWithRange(numbersStringArray.startIndex.successor()..<numbersStringArray.endIndex.predecessor())
```

but this makes the code longer ;-)

Comment: thank you, but I would like something shorter if possible. Something like Array(numbersStringArray)

Comment: You can use `flatMap` to filter out non-integer strings

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, I updated the answer. @IamMashed Go for the most efficient rather than the shortest code.

Comment: @Wain So you are saying my wish is not possible?

Comment: @IamMashed You could always write an `Array` extension with a custom initialiser to do this. I have [written an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37399023/2976878) demonstrating how you could do this.