# Convert array.description string to Array

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there any simple method to convert string that looks like that: [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]] to array with arrays?

I will be glad.

Comment: That does not look like the description of a *dictionary.* How did you obtain the string? – Better choose a format like JSON if you have to convert dictionaries/arrays to a string and back.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I thought about Array...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391290/convert-string-array-representation-of-integers-into-array-of-integers-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to convert it to JSON and back:

```
let str = "[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]"
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let arr = json as? [[Int]] {
        print(arr)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made that method for it and it works:

```
func convertToArray(string: String) -> [[Int]] {
    var arrayOrder = 0
    var mainArray: [[Int]] = []
    var array: [Int] = []

    for character in string.characters {
        if character == "[" {
            arrayOrder += 1
        }

        if arrayOrder >= 2 && character != "[" && character != "]" && character != "," {
            let integer: Int = Int(String(character))!
            array.append(integer)
        }

        if character == "]" {
            if arrayOrder >= 2 {
                mainArray.append(array)
                array = []
            }

            arrayOrder -= 1
        }
    }

    return mainArray
}
```

Comment: It is only if we have one level of arrays in main array.